# Laravel Mix. Broken public path with "npm run hot"

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

I use my own public folder that is not in the root of the project. 
./bds/public instead of ./public

**My laravel-mix config:**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue'],
        alias: {
            '@': __dirname + '/resources'
        },
    }
});

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'js/app.js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css/app.css');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
} else {
    mix.sourceMaps();
}
```

In "npm run watch" mode I got app.js path as expected. 
But in "npm run hot" I got incorrect public path:

```
GET http://172.18.107.133/bds/public//localhost:8080//js/app.js 404 (Not Found)
```

As you can see there is //localhost:8080/ in the middle of the path.
I don't need it. 
 How can I remove it to get the path:

```
http://172.18.107.133/bds/public/js/app.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know your question is old, but recently I went through the same mistake, and after days of researching, I only got it through the following instruction.

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.options({
    hmrOptions: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '8080'
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks!
I understood that it's not a good practice to build client with server together. It's much easier to separate them, add JWT auth and use bult-in node dev server for HMR development.

Comment: please, if so, mark the answer as a solution (by clicking on the checkmark)